# How to relink an existing schematic (.asc) and simulation plot (.raw) in a new session of LTspice?

Tags: ltspice

I've been using LTspice for several weeks now to develop a custom circuit. After running a simulation I study the results by looking at the plot, making good use of the linkage between the schematic and the plot pane where I click on various nodes and components in the schematic to see the corresponding waveforms pop up in the plot. Linkage in the other direction (alt-left-click on an identifier in the plot pane to highlight the corresponding component or node in the schematic pane) works too. Very nifty! However, my design has grown to the point where it is not always possible to complete my work in a single session with LTspice. Sometimes I have to shut down my computer and go home!

When I come back to the project in a later work session, I can open the .asc file and the corresponding .raw file in LTspice, but the tool no longer seems to recognize the connection between the two. The graphical real-time user interface features described above no longer work. It seems I have to re-run the simulation in order to re-establish the linkage and take full advantage of the power of the tool. This is fine when the simulations are small, but I am getting to the point where this is no longer practical (i.e., overnight simulation runs). Am I missing something on how to operate LTspice in such a way as to reestablish the behind-the-scenes linkages established in a previous work session without having to re-run the entire simulation?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to manipulate the linking manually.  Might be a good question to run by the peeps over at the [LTspice Google Group](https://groups.io/g/LTspice), or even shooting an email over to `LTspice@analog.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Ste.  I'm beginning to think the same thing.  This is a question pertaining to LTspice internals, so raising the issue with the "owner" of LTspice would definitely be the best way to answer it, provided I can get their attention!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with LTSpice.
What I would do is install LTSpice in Oracle VirtualBox. You can save the machine state and stop a running virtual machine and load/continue later.

https://www.oracle.com/virtualization/virtualbox/

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'm getting by for now with a spreadsheet where I stored the syntax for all the signals I might be interested in plotting so that I can just copy-paste them into the "Add Traces" dialog in the plot itself.  But VirtualBox sounds like a great solution for any problem that requires a long computer run time without interruption - something I will look into if necessary.

Comment: Great idea! I wouldn’t have thought of this.